# Server Error in '/' Application. Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: migration

At present I am using SharePoint Services 3.0. I want to upgrade to 2013. First I run the `preupgradecheck`. It showed one of the error as

> Pending upgrade operation detected in this farm.

For that I ran the command `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait`
After that all my sites including central administration were down and application pools also stopped.

After number of trails I tried

Windows Internal database service was set as Network Service, changed it to Local and restarted the service 
- Then ran the command `stsadm psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force` 
as per [this site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_26292249.html)

Now everything is fine except for one site. It is not working still and showing error as

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
>      Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.OpenWebInternal(String bstrUrl, Guid& pguidID, String& pbstrRequestAccessEmail, UInt32& pwebVersion, String&

Please let me know the reason and solution as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

its related to your web.config!

i presume it hasnt changed as of yet. Goto your site web.config on the server:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories

look for the folder that your site is within, the folder is named by the port number it uses!

go into the folder and look for `web.config` can you see other web.configs???? like `web.bak` or usually it will be somthing like `web_2013_02_08_08_41_02.bak`.

if you do you can rename the web.config to web.configBak,
goto a later version of the web.bak and rename it to web.config,
now reload the page and it should work! if it does you can compart the difference between them to see what has changed!

if you dont have another version than create a new webapplication and copy the web.config over and compare and update accordingly.

If there is so resource your using on the site it could be todo with too many fields or it could of reverted if it was changed!

look for appsettings and see if its higher than the default of 1000

```
   <appSettings>
      <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
   </appSettings>
```